# не могу понять в чём конкретно состоит ошибка. Помогите разобраться

Tags: python

```py
temperature_exact = 39.3 # (жара) 
temperature_approx = int(float(temperature_exact)) + 1  # преобразуйте значение в целое и прибавь 1 

print("За окном" + temperature_exact + "градусов Цельсия". 'Это почти' + temperature_approx )   # допишите код здесь
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3
    print("За окном" + temperature_exact + "градусов Цельсия". 'Это почти' + temperature_approx )   # допишите код здесь
                                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Когда после строки стоит точка, то после этой точки ожидается название метода. Но вы вместо этого написали ещё одну строку, и такая синтаксическая конструкция в питоне недопустима

Answer (score 3):

```
print("За окном " + temperature_exact + " градусов Цельсия. Это почти " + temperature_approx + ".")
```

Answer (score 3):

вообще складывать разные типы данных (строки, дробные числа, целые числа) не правильно, если нужно напечатать строку в которой нужно вывести другой формат данных используй команду `format`

```
print("За окном {} градусов Цельсия. Это почти {}".format(temperature_exact , temperature_approx ))
```

подробней о форматировании строк можно прочитать [здесь](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/formatirovanie-strok-metod-format.html)

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/